# Why does my Rails form always return a `POST` when I explicitly calling `PUT`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request, put, form-for

Here's my examples that produce the same result :

```
# `enterprise_registration` is an already created/saved object

form_for enterprise_registration, method: :put do |format|; format; end
form_for enterprise_registration, url: logo_url, method: :put do |format|; format; end
form_for enterprise_registration, url: logo_url, html: {method: :put} do |format|; format; end
```

This returns the form with the `method` attribute set to `POST`.

Why is that happening, do you think? And how can I make it a `:put` request?

**Update**

I now understand that Rails forms embed a hidden `_method` and set it to `put`, but my form is still getting delivered as a `POST` that is preventing my form from finding my matching `PUT` `URL`

Answer (score 4):

`form` tag has only `GET` or `POST` method allowed. See also [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) for more explanation. Rails, however, has his own method to handle `GET/POST/PUT/PATCH` requests. If you would examine any of your `form` defined as either `form_for` or `form_tag` in Rails, you will notice that first element of the form is a hidden `<div>` which contain two hidden fields:

```
<div style="display:none">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch">  
  <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="9i5eRhwhx4NhvSxqIJm6cv9x6NSlY82hpNpfrpk/I0c=">
</div>
```

First field called `_method` contains the form action which is the request type for controller.

Comment: The trouble is is that when I click submit, it still submits as a POST and doesn't find the appropriate matching PUT URL.. But I do see that the hidden variable `_method` is there and set to `PUT`

Comment: What does the controller is saying?

Comment: `Started POST "/enterprise/register/21/logo?[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object]&_=1415653774871" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-10 13:10:04 -0800`

Comment: Interesting. Do you send simply via `f.submit` without any asynchronous requests?

Comment: That's correct. I notice if I take away `remote: true`, it will perform the POST but work, so I assume the secret `put` is getting passed that way. So now I believe I have it narrowed to `remote: true` not disrupting the `put` request

Comment: Well, with `remote: true` you're having asynchronous request. If you remove it, server logs will show `Started PUT...`? For some reason using `remote: true`, form serialization is totally messed up. What with `jquery_ujs`, do you have it included?

Answer (score 1):

Web browsers are actually only programmed to receive POST and GET requests (I'm not sure why). The way Rails mimics full REST (which includes put and delete) is include those in hidden fields. So technically it's sending a POST, but with the PUT attached sort of awkwardly in that hidden field.

I'm assuming that Rails is still doing that sort of conversion behind the scenes still.